# Getting Location of Command in Popen

Tags: python

I am currently debugging a cmd run with `Popen`.

It looks like:

```
cmd = ['test', 'arg1', 'arg2']
Popen(cmd)
```

`test` is a python script and I have multiple on my computer. How do I tell which `test` is getting picked up when I call `Popen()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Linux, try doing a `Popen()` or `subprocess.check_output()` on the [`which`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/which) command, passing in `test` as an argument.

For example:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(["which", "test"])
b'/Users/joeyoung/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/test\n'
```